# Temporary Lifetime in Arc in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am struggling to understand temporary lifetime concept in Rust.

Let's say I have the following struct with the `Arc` field:

```
struct MyStruct {
    arc_field: Arc<Mutex<i32>>,
}
```

When i try to access inner i32 field inside from the clone of the `arc_field` it is complaining about

> Temporary value dropped here while still borrowed

Here is how I am trying to retrieve it:

```
let my_field = my_struct.arc_field.clone().lock().unwrap();
```

Why is that I need to use let binding to increase it's lifetime?

Here is [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=a6adbca76ac303f8a3c1f0a4f3f9d19c)

Comment: Why do you clone the `Arc`?

Comment: I want to use the ARC in between threads and so I clone the Arc and send it to spawned threads.

Answer (score 4):

`clone` returns a new instance that you do not store inside a variable. So it is a temporary value. You must store your copy inside a variable to make it non temporary:

```
let my_field = my_struct.arc_field.clone(); // You have a non temporary lifetime
let my_field = my_field.lock().unwrap();
```

You cannot use directly the cloned value because `lock` borrows it, and the borrow cannot outlive the value.

Comment: I know that I can handle it with storing the clone to the another variable which is increasing the lifetime from temporary to the scope but why do I really need it? I mean, I have clone as temporary and why can't I call lock() from that temporary clone value?

Comment: @AkinerAlkan Because `lock` borrows the data. I'll add this in my answer.